# Ubuntu server with apache2 installed

Tags: boot, server, apache2

I have set up an ubunto server 18.4 lts with wordpress on it. In the package where there apache2 and mysql.

Now I have some problems with the apache2 server it will not start the http for wordpress and I have worked on it for two days now and cant get any further. Or at leat i do not know what to do.

When I write the command `sudo systemctl status apache2.service` Ill get an error log for the wordpress and it will not make the server active.

[This is what I get directly from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUMr9.png)

It would be a great help if anybody would know what i could do to make it work.

Thanks a lot and have a good day.

Comment: I've now tried ti look at the firewall but i do not think its the answer... I'm running out of options...

Comment: It was the firewall that was messing with my apache2. Just run over the firewall and open op the ports if any has shut down.

Comment: Look in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Is there anything useful there? If not, do `sudo apachectl configtest` and add the output to your question.

Comment: It had something in it. But i tried the last thing I could think of and that helped. But know my wordpress site isnt showing... This is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the firewall it has somehow changed the setting for the apache2 so it couldnt connect through port 80.

[now the apache is up and running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWpv2.png)